# Spring Roo user registration, management and login

Tags: spring-roo

I'm new to Spring Roo, looking for a quick way to start enterprise Java apps with basic functionality.

From this point of view, the very first thing I need to do is a simple user registration and login page, with the usual set of features: login, logout, confirm email address, reset password and edit user information.

There was a very good add-on called [Typical Security](http://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-typical-security/) but it's too old (no support for Roo 1.2) and has no continuity (as far as I know)

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent 10 min copying what I needed from their source jar into my project. If you like everything the plugin provides, put together a patch for the new roo and push it up!
https://code.google.com/p/gvnix/source/browse/#svn%2Frepo%2Fcom%2Fxsoftwarelabs%2Fspring%2Froo%2Faddon%2Ftypicalsecurity%2Fcom.xsoftwarelabs.spring.roo.addon.typicalsecurity%2F0.1.5